# std::sort on pair which the 2nd element has no comparator

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how is it that the following code is being compiled without warning/error.

This is the the piece of code that I see in the project that I am working on in office. (variable/class name has been changed)

```
vector<pair<time_t, ClassA *> > vec = getVecFromSomewhere();
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

I have checked the source code of ClassA, which I do not see any comparator being implemented. So is it true that only the first element of a pair requires comparator?

Edit: all instances of ClassA originate from the same vector.

Comment: This is `ClassA*` not `ClassA`, you are sorting pointer not value.

Comment: [This `std::pair` comparison operator reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ClassA` might not have an `operator<`, but that doesn't matter, because you're storing `ClassA*` in your pair, not `ClassA`. You *can* compare pointers, so your code works.

```
ClassA as [10];
as[0] < as[1]; //invalid, compares ClassAs
as < as+1; //valid, compares ClassA*s
```

Note that you need to be very careful with the semantics of your comparison. Do you *really* want to be comparing those pointers? Do they point to the same array object? If not, you're off into the fun fun land of undefined behaviour as soon as you compare them. If so, that ordering might still not be the one you want.

Comment: A slight addendum might be in order: You can only use relative comparison (less than, greater than) for *related* pointers (like for your array example). Otherwise only equality/inequality is defined.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:  But you can use `std::less(ptr1, ptr2)` on unrelated pointers - the OP might want to write a comparison function which does that.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is incorrect. [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) defines `operator<`. It compares lexicographically, that is, the second elements are only compared if the first are equal.

The exact standardese (n4606):

> `template <class T1, class T2>`
>
> `constexpr bool operator<(const pair<T1, T2>& x, const pair<T1, T2>& y)`
>
> Returns: `x.first < y.first || (!(y.first < x.first) && x.second < y.second)`.

This case is a bit special, because it's undefined to compare pointers to objects that are not parts of the same object/array.

Comment: you mean the behaviour is undefined here?

Comment: @Mox can't say. Are all `ClassA*` pointers pointing to the same array?

Comment: @Mox: The behavior almost certainly is unintended, even if it would be formally defined.

Comment: that means in the event that, these elements are not from the same array, the behaviour will be undefined

Comment: @Mox as far as I can tell, yes. `pair`'s operator `<` is defined in terms of operator `<`, not `std::less`, which guarantees a total (unspecified) ordering of pointers. Which is a tad surprising if I am to be honest.

Comment: Anyway thanks for pointing out, something new learned today. =)